# Moment generating function $n$ moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Suppose that a probability distribution $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$ has only $n$ finite positive moments $\{m_k\}_{k=1}^n$. That is, $m_k = \int_{[0,\infty)}x^k\mu(\text{d} x) < +\infty$ for $k \in \{ 1,\,2,\,\ldots , n\}$ and $m_k = \int_{[0,\infty)}x^k\mu(\text{d} x) = +\infty$ for $k > n$. Is there any justification for approximating the associated moment generating function $\phi(s)$ by the polynomial $$1 + m_1s + m_2\frac{s^2}{2}+ \ldots + m_n\frac{s^n}{n!}$$ for non-positive $s$ near zero?

Comment: I don’t understand your first condition. Do you mean the other moments are infinite?

Comment: Yes, that was the intention. I amended the question to make this explicit.

Comment: Doesn't that mean the MGF doesn't exist for $s > 0$?

Comment: Yes, I am interested in s ≤ 0.